# How can I fix tooltip with overflow-x and overflow-y?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I did horizontal scroll and also I added tooltip, but tooltip is not working. I am using react-lightweight-tooltip library. I trying with with z-index but it is not working also, I don't know why. Can anybody help me with that. Thank you !

Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mendeleev-jb1be

Answer (score 0):

Your custom styles are hiding the tooltip, specifically the `bottom: 100%` on `tooltip`.

Remove that or adjust it so that the tooltip shows.

I tested this by using `bottom: 0`, and that seems to fix it.

Here:

```
export const underlyingsTooltipStyle = {
  /* OMITTED IRRELEVANT STYLES */
  tooltip: {
   position: 'absolute',
   zIndex: '99',
   background: '#000',
   bottom: '0',
   left: '50%',
   marginBottom: '10px',
   padding: '5px',
   WebkitTransform: 'translateX(-50%)',
   msTransform: 'translateX(-50%)',
   OTransform: 'translateX(-50%)',
   transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
 },
 /* OMITTED IRRELEVANT STYLES */
]
```